# Setting output parameter in Python script tool to be PDF?

Tags: arcpy, pdf, python-script-tool, parameters, dynamic

I need to allow a user to input a path and name where they would like to save their new map book PDF on their computer/drive.

I have created a script where the user can input their mxd with data driven pages, input their title map, append the two PDF documents and save the appended PDF, but it's all hard coded and I'd like to create a script where they can select where to save their new appended PDF when they open it in the toolbox.

I need the script to be dynamic. I'm stumbling on setting up the parameters. I'm unsure what the Output PDF data type should be set as in the toolbox. None of the selections seem to fit.

Aside from "Output" in the "Parameter Properties" should I change anything else?

Answer (score 4):

Set it as a [File type](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001500000035000000). You can use [parameter validation](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00150000002v000000) to ensure the file extension is ".pdf" or as @blah238 notes,  use the filter option to restrict file type to pdf.

Comment: +1, except that you can skip the validation part and just set the Filter option to 'pdf'.